# How to a row in a dataframe based on certain conditions

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this:

| id | ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | white |
| 2 | south asian |
| 2 | other |
| 3 | other |
| 4 | white |
| 4 | south asian |

as seen above there is potential for an id to have two ethnicity values. How would I go about removing these 'other' rows if that id already has an entry such as "white" or "south asian" while keeping the "white" or "south asian" entry?

I have noticed there are entries which also have south asian along with a white entry

My priority would be South Asian > White > Other in terms of keeping rows

So an expected output would be

| id | ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | white |
| 2 | south asian |
| 3 | other |
| 4 | south asian |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is to get the prioritized 'ethnicity' per 'id', convert the column 'ethnicity' to `ordered` with `levels` specified in the order of preference, then do a group by 'id' and `filter` the `first` available level in that order

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
  mutate(ethnicity = ordered(ethnicity, 
    c( "south asian", "white", "other"))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(ethnicity %in% first(levels(droplevels(ethnicity)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     id ethnicity  
  <int> <ord>      
1     1 white      
2     2 south asian
3     3 other      
4     4 south asian
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), ethnicity = c("white", 
"south asian", "other", "other", "white", "south asian")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @LeoCooper can you please update your post with a new example and expected.  It is not clear with prioriization

Comment: Sorry, i tried this but it removes both rows, i dont think i made it clear enough in the original post but i want to keep the non other one such as white or south asian

Comment: yes will do 1 second

Comment: @LeoCooper do you have more preference to `white` compared to `south asian`?

Comment: the other way around, south asian would have higher priority over white

Comment: @LeoCooper try the update

Comment: hmmm, there is one specifc id im looking at which has both south asian and white and when i run that code only the white is left

Comment: @LeoCooper if you can update your post with your expected output, it is easier to crosscheck.  From your earlier comments, I thought you want to keep only the one with the preference if present

Comment: I've updated the main post with outputs, running that code one comment above seems to remove all rows

Comment: @LeoCooper your expected shows the same output I get with the updated one

Comment: @LeoCooper If I can quote your expected, you get 4 rows , 1 row for each id, `1 - white, 2 - south asian, 3 - other, 4 - south asian`. which is what I get from the update

Comment: That's what is confusing me so much lol in my actual table i have an id '2116' with south asian and white entries and then when i run the code only the white entry is left

Comment: @LeoCooper i thiink you are using my previous code, instead of the updated with `c( "south asian", "white", "other")`.  Previously, I used `c("white", "south asian", "other")`

Comment: I thought so too but im using: h_ethnicity %>%
  mutate(ethnicity = ordered(ethnicity, c( "South asian", "White", "Other"))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(ethnicity %in% first(levels(droplevels(ethnicity)))) %>%
  ungroup

Comment: @LeoCooper please note that the case should match the case in the column i.e. if your column values are 'south asian' and you use `South asian`, there is a difference in case for `S` vs `s`

Comment: Pretty sure that's it i had "South asian" in the code but "South Asian" in my columns, thank you so much!